# Pickimino Game (2+ players)

Tags: java

I am in the middle of creating a game in java called Pickomino. This code is fine for one player and is running normal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player1 = new Player(); // Dhmiourgeia enws paikth
            Player player2 = new Player(); 
    Board board1 = new Board(); // Dhmiourgeia tou board

    /** Crazy Tests ( gia 2 gurous sunexomenous o idios paikths) */
    //for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) {


    // Ripsh twn zariwn
    while ((player1.isPlayOn()) && (remainingRolls(ROLLS,counterOfDice) > 0)) {
        System.out.print("Oi zaries sou einai: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingRolls(ROLLS,counterOfDice); i++) {
            rolls[i] = randomRoll();
            System.out.print(rolls[i] + " ");
        }

        if (noMoreRolls(rolls,pickedDice)) 
            break; // Telos gurou tou paikth, se periptwsh pou den epitrepetai na shkwsei alla zaria apo to trapezi
        System.out.print("\nDialekse ena zari / paketo omoiwn zariwn apo ta parapanw: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        // Elegxos viable kinhshs tou paikth
        while (player1.isPicked(choice, pickedDice)) {
            System.out.println("To exeis hdh auto.");
            System.out.print("Dialekse ena allo zari / paketo omoiwn zariwn apo ta parapanw: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Topothethsh zariwn epiloghs sthn stiva tou paikth
        for (int i = 0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
            if (choice == rolls[i]) {
                pickedDice[counterOfDice] = rolls[i];
                counterOfDice++;
            }
            rolls[i] = 0;
        }       
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pickedDice));

        // Prosthesh zariwn
        sumOfDice = currentSumOfDice(pickedDice);
        System.out.println("Mexri stigmh to athrisma einai " + sumOfDice);

        // Termatismos gurou gia ton current paikth
        if ((sumOfDice > 20) && (remainingRolls(ROLLS,counterOfDice) > 0) && (player1.canIPick(pickedDice))) {
            System.out.print("Sunexizoume? ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            player1.isEndOfYourTurn(choice);
        }
    }

    // Emfanish apotelesmatos
    //System.out.println("sum = " + sumOfDice);


    // Check pontwn me pontous sto trapezi **PREPEI NA ALLAKSEI**
    if (player1.canIPick(pickedDice)) {
            board1.removeAWorm(sumOfDice);
            player1.setPoints( (sumOfDice - 17) / 4 );
        }
    System.out.println("kartes = " + board1.getRemainingWorms());
    System.out.println("\nSe auton ton guro phres: " + player1.getPoints() + " skoulikia.");


    /** Crazy Tests*/

    //resetRolls();
    //for (int i = 0; i < pickedDice.length; i++) {
        //pickedDice[i] = 0;
    //}
    //player1.setPlayOn();
//}

}
```

My question is: if I need to import 2 more players what do I have to do? I know that I can c/p the code 2 more times and play with *switch* but I found it to be kind of stupid.
My problem is that I have the checks (e.x. **while (player1.isPicked(choice, pickedDice))**) for player1 only as you can see. Is there a way to re-write my main code and each time to have the active player on? Do I have to import a new method or something?

Comment: Why didnt you think about the design before implementing??.. Redesigning/ restructuring will take more time than you actually took to write your code... And believe me it will have lot of bugs ...

Comment: Cause I am new @ programming and I thought that if It plays for one player wouldn't be hard to be played from more. I will re-write the code anyway cause I will create it for Android when I am sure that works in Java in the first place. Do you have something to suggest a way how my code can be more *general* and not only for player1? Should I create an ArrayList of players?

Comment: Well... there's no good way to do a bad thing... Keep a list of players put a for loop and loop over all the players . put all that logic of yours in a function and call it in the for loop.. And be ready for lots of errors...

Comment: K I will try this. If I wanted to write again for multiplayer what I should have in my mind?

Comment: The first thing that you should have in mind is the fact that -" Your structure will/should not change later". Come up with a design that will effectively handle multiple players.. understand and design how different players interact... Think of all possible problems you could face and "make sure you have a solution or a workaround for them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a data structure that holds your Player objects.  If this is a turn based game, an ArrayList will work nicely, with a variable that is the index of the Player whose turn it is.  When the player finishes his turn, increment the index and then check to see if it needs to wrap around to zero yet.

If the game is not turn based, then a Map of some kind works nicely for getting the right Player object.  When I code multiplayer realtime online games I normally use a ConcurrentHashMap.

As a general rule, if you think that a game will need to be multiplayer and not single player, you need to take that into account before starting to implement it, even if you implement single player first.

Comment: hello. Thanks for your answer. Yeah it is a turned based game and I will try the ArrayList as you say. Thanks for the answer.